# My state elements (Pokemon) rendering in mixed up order using Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

Apologies, I hope this isn't a silly question -

I am trying to get more familiar with React & typescript by making a little Pokedex application, however, I cannot seem to figure why after I initially load the page, that a couple of refreshes later some of the items are completely out of order - Part of me thinks it is a fetching issue with two calls working on top of one another but I am unsure of how to proceed?

I have provided my code below:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { PokemonType } from "./models/pokemonType";
import Pokemon from "./components/Pokemon";

function App() {
  const [pokedex, setPokedex] = useState<PokemonType[] | []>([]);
  const limit = 151;

  const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    collectPokemon(limit);
  }, []);

  const collectPokemon = async (limit: number) => {
    axiosInstance.get(`pokemon?limit=${limit}`).then((res) => {
      const data = res.data.results;

      Promise.all(data).then((results) => {
        results.map((pkmn) => {
          mapPokemon(pkmn.name);
        });
      });
    });
  };

  const mapPokemon = async (name: string) => {
    axiosInstance.get(`pokemon/${name}`).then((res) => {
      const data: PokemonType = res.data;
      setPokedex((currentList) => [...currentList, data]);
    });
  };

  console.log(pokedex);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Pokédex App</h1>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-10 m-10">
        {pokedex.map((mon: PokemonType) => (
          <Pokemon key={mon.id} name={mon.name} id={mon.id} types={mon.types} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

## Pokemon.tsx

```
import { PokemonType } from "../models/pokemonType";

const Pokemon = (props: PokemonType) => {
  const { name, id, types } = props;
  const paddedIndex = ("000" + (id ? id : id)).slice(-3);

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-600 rounded-2xl p-2 transform h-180 min-w-250 transition duration-500 hover:scale-180 hover:drop-shadow-[0_10px_10px_rgba(0,0,0,.5)] border-gray-950 border-4 overflow-clip">
      <div className="bg-gray-900 text-white rounded-xl p-2 w-20 text-center absolute top-2 right-2 font-pokemonGB border-white border-2">
        #{paddedIndex}
      </div>
      <img
        key={id}
        className="scale-125 relative"
        width={150}
        height={150}
        alt={name}
        src={`https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/${paddedIndex}.png`}
      />
      <div className="font-pokemonGB text-black bg-white w-auto text-sm text-center capitalize rounded-tl-2xl p-2 absolute right-0 bottom-0 slant-x-[30deg] border-gray-950 border-4 -m-1">
        {name}
      </div>
      <div
        key={Math.random()}
        className=" flex flex-row fixed right-2 top-16 space-x-3"
      >
        {types?.map((item) => (
          <div className="bg-red-500 rounded-lg p-2 capitalize border-gray-950 border-2 ">
            <p>{item.type?.name}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pokemon;
```

I have tried calling the fetches without axios and using setLoading states to no avail, Ideally all Pokemon should be displayed in order.

Comment: `useEffect` runs twice in a strict mode. You are using `Promise.all` wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look more like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  collectPokemon(limit);
}, []);

const collectPokemon = async (limit: number) => {
  const res = await axiosInstance.get(`pokemon?limit=${limit}`);
  const promises = res.data.results.map((name) => mapPokemon(name));
  const pokemons = await Promise.all(promises);
  setPokedex(pokemons);
};

const mapPokemon = async (name: string) => {
  const res = await axiosInstance.get(`pokemon/${name}`);
  return res.data;
};
```

You shouldn't really update state in a loop

Comment: Thank you Konrad for the speedy and great response, that worked a treat, I need to brush up on my promises logic! Thanks again!